# How to add virtual directory to the default url of a project generated by angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, virtual-directory

in a project generated by angular-cli, if you run:

```
ng serve -o
```

The browser will open a tab with this link by default:

```
http://localhost:4200
```

I want to add a virtual directory to this url, something like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/CompanyName/Product/Web
```

I know the **--host** and **--port** option can change the host and the port of this url, but I can't find an option to add the virtual directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--base-href` or `-bh` flag for that

```
ng serve --base-href /CompanyName/Product/Web -o
```